# What does (array) do in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Does this code do anything? Somehow I made a mistake and wrote this code. However, this mistake turned out to be a boon. This solved my problem :D

$arr_centres = (array) $centres_array[0];

But I want to know what this does. The centres_array is like this:

```
stdClass Object (

[ExampleCentre] => Array ( 

[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[ID] => 14 
[Name] => mycity
[Code] => exm 
[Email] => example.web@example.com 
[FB] => 
[Address1] => Exm, example 
[City] => Hakuna Matata 
[PostCode] => 000000
[County] => 
[Fax] => Fax 
[Telephone] => 000222888
[Location] => 01.000000,-0.00004 
[URL] => /holla/hakuna/example
)
```

Comment: you wrote it and you dont know what it does? Does that mean you copied it and dont know what it does? Just curious

Comment: The code is already existing. I am just working in it. I am not given enough time to actually sit down and understand the architecture. A bad practice. But I have to do both the things simultaneously i.e. understanding the archi and solving the bugs :(

Comment: i was just curious, (array) is a casting operator. It makes sure the result of $centres_array is an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It casts your stdClass object as an array.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

It'll create an array with single index whose value will be value of $centres_array[0đ which is your stdClass object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stdClass object casting it to an array will produce an array with object public properties as keys => values. For instance the following code

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 'value1';
$obj->bar = 'value2';
var_dump((array) $obj);
```

will give you

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```